# Primefaces PickList transfer event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a picklist that contains a list of services

```
                     <h5> Pick A Service </h5>
                     <p:pickList id="pojoPickList"
                     responsive="true"                                 
                     value="#{brancheController.serviceNames}"
                     var="service" 
                     itemValue="#{service}"
                     itemLabel="#{service.serviceName}"
                     converter="#{serviceConverter}">

      <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available Services</f:facet>
      <f:facet name="targetCaption">Assigned Services</f:facet>
         <p:ajax event="transfer"
                 listener="#{brancheController.onTransfer}"/>
        </p:pickList>
```

and in the backing Bean i have this method that get trigered whenever we have a transfer event

```
    public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event) {

    if (event.isAdd()) {
        for (Object item : event.getItems()) {
            notDuplicatedServices.remove((Service) item);
            serviceNamesTarget.add((Service) item);
        }
    } else if (event.isRemove()) {
        log.info(event.getItems().size());
        for (Object object: event.getItems()) {
        notDuplicatedServices.add((Service) item);
        serviceNamesTarget.remove((Service) item);
       }
    }
```

When adding a service TransferEvent.isAdd() works fine but when removing a service event.getItems() is always empty

Can you please help me how to solve this and get removed services

Thank you in advance .

Comment: It's working in the showcase https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml

Comment: I changed the implementation of the converter and now it works